# maxnames in biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, author-number

I'm trying to set `maxnames` in my biber option, but it doesn't work.

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,german]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{section}{\large} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authortitle,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{paul.bib}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{txfonts} %Schriftart Times New Roman

\begin{document}

foobar\cite{pisae2003}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my paul.bib:

```
@ARTICLE{pisae2003,
   author = {{Prenzel, Manfred and Baumert, Jürgen and Blum,Werner and Lehmann, Rainer and Leutner, Detlev and Neubrand,Michael and Pekrun,Reinhard Rost,Jürgen and Schiefele, Ulrich}},
   title = {PISA-2003},
   subtitle = {Ergebnisse des zweiten Ländervergleichs. Zusammenfassung},
   url = {http://pisa.ipn.uni-kiel.de/PISA2003_E_Zusammenfassung.pdf},
   lastchecked = {20.\,März.\,2013},
   year = 2005,}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). :) Could you clarify, what is not working? Because your code deosn't involve any maxnames commands in the MWE.

Tip: Also, you can make the code stand out by indenting the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: You have an additional pair of braces in the `author` field that should be removed: with your input you're telling Biber that you have only *one* author (with a very peculiar name).

Answer (score 7):

You have an additional pair of braces in your `author` field that makes impossible for Biber to count the number of authors: you're specifying, according to the syntax rules, only one author.

For setting the maximum number of authors shown there are various options; here's how you can limit the number of authors shown in citations to three. The `file contents*` environment is just a convenience for making the example self contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{pisae2003,
   author = {Prenzel, Manfred and Baumert, Jürgen and Blum, Werner and 
             Lehmann, Rainer and Leutner, Detlev and Neubrand, Michael and
             Pekrun, Reinhard and Rost, Jürgen and Schiefele, Ulrich},
   title = {PISA-2003},
   subtitle = {Ergebnisse des zweiten Ländervergleichs. Zusammenfassung},
   url = {http://pisa.ipn.uni-kiel.de/PISA2003_E_Zusammenfassung.pdf},
   lastchecked = {20.\,März.\,2013},
   year = 2005,}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,german]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}

\usepackage{txfonts} %Schriftart Times New Roman

\usepackage[
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=5,
  mincitenames=3,
  maxbibnames=1000,
  backend=biber
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

A citation: \cite{pisae2003}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here we're telling LaTeX to show three authors in a citation when the total number of them is more than five. So up to five authors are shown, but when their number is six or more, only the first three will appear in a citation (adjust to what you prefer). Conversely, by setting `maxbibnames=1000`, we're saying that any list of authors will be printed fully (well, not if there are more than one thousand of them).

The relation between `maxbibnames` and `minbibnames` is the same as between `maxcitenames` and `minbibnames`.

Setting `maxnames` is the same as setting `maxbibnames` and `maxcitenames` to the same value; similarly for `minnames`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I really understand the thing with maxnames. My problem were the double-braces. Only one thing: In my faculty they want the latin expresssio (et al.) not the german one (u.a.) How can I tell biber to do that?

Comment: OK. I found that in the web (with \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
} So everything is OK now. Thank you so much foe taking time to help