# change maxnumber in the middle of document with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, author-number

Is there a possibility to change biblatex's maxnames option in
the middle of the document?

Background: I am including a list of my own publication at the
end of my thesis.  I include also some papers where I am not the
first author, so I need to show the full list of authors here.

The most helpful comments I found are in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106305/15392).

As far as I understand:

1. Using the options field in the .bib file won't work without some additional work and duplication of entries in the bib file, since I might cite the same article in the main document (where I want to have only maxnames displayed at maximum) and in my publications list (where I need full author list.
2. Duplicating my own articles into a second file would be possible.  I'd still prefer a pure biblatex solution without the need to adapt the .bib file.
   If that is the only way, though, I'd need advice on how to get this to work as well.

Many thanks in advance!

Regards,
Andreas

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{currvita}

% just for demonstration
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=3}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Main Document}
Here I write about our method \parencite{herrmann}.

\printbibliography

\clearpage
\begin{cv}{Max Mustermann}

  %% personal information
  \begin{cvlist}{Personal Information}
    \item[Date of Birth] 01 March 2013
    \item[Place of Birth] Berlin
    \item[Nationality] German
  \end{cvlist}

  %% Publications
  %% \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99}
  \setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{0mm}
  \begin{cvlist}{Publications}
    \item \fullcite{herrmann}
  \end{cvlist}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are going to populate your "List of Publications" through `\fullcite` commands, you can issue the command

```
\AtNextCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}
```

just before each `\fullcite` in the "List of Publications".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{currvita}

% just for demonstration
%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=3}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Main Document}
Here I write about our method \parencite{herrmann}.

\printbibliography

\clearpage
\begin{cv}{Max Mustermann}

  %% personal information
  \begin{cvlist}{Personal Information}
    \item[Date of Birth] 01 March 2013
    \item[Place of Birth] Berlin
    \item[Nationality] German
  \end{cvlist}

  %% Publications
  %% \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99}
  \setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{0mm}
  \begin{cvlist}{Publications}
    \AtNextCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}
    \item \fullcite{herrmann}
  \end{cvlist}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, if you are not using commands like `\fullcite` before your "List of Publications", load `biblatex` with the options `maxcitenames=99,maxbibnames=3`:

```
\usepackage[maxcitenames=99,maxbibnames=3]{biblatex}
```

If you, instead, are going to print a second bibliography, issue the command

```
\AtNextBibliography{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}
```

just before it and you will have the first bibliography with `maxnames=3` and the second with `maxnames=99`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Indeed, it works nicely with my MWE.  Not with the real thesis, though.  I'll have to look for interfering packages/options.  Do you have an educated guess, what might be the culprit?

Comment: @Andreas Unfortunately, I have not a crystal ball :-) Do you have any custom code involving `biblatex`?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  I use some package options (natbib, ...) but they work fine in the MWE as well.  Other than that I do not see anything obvious (search for 'bib' and 'cite' returned nothing).  I was just hoping you had that crystal ball to save some of my time checking...

Comment: Turned out I am just not able to read properly. I had not realized that `\AtNextCitekey` only affects *one* citation.  It works now.  Thanks  again.

Comment: @Andreas It was written not too well in my answer. See the edit.

Comment: `\AtNextCite` works as well. Is there a significant difference to `\AtNextCitekey`?