# Print all authors in \citename when maxnames=N is set

Tags: biblatex, citing

What I would like to do, is to print the full author list for a reference,  in a document where I've set `maxnames` to a small number. I'd like the names printed as *Firstname Lastname*. The list of authors can be printed with `\citename{<ref>}{author}`, but it will be truncated with *et al.* when `maxnames` is in effect.  I guess I need to define a new format for use with `\citename`, but I haven't quite been able to wrap my head around how that should be done.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=3]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This should print Aks\i{}n et al. (2006): \textcite{aksin}

\bigskip

Here I would like to print all the authors, not just `Özge Aks\i{}n et al':
\citename{aksin}{author}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155864/89417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a customized command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=3, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% creation of \citeallnames command
\newcommand\citeallnames{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\citename}

\begin{document}
This should print Aks\i{}n et al. (2006): \textcite{aksin}

\bigskip

All authors with customized command:
\citeallnames{aksin}{author}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My recommendation `\newrobutstcmd*{\citeallnames}{\AtNextCitekey}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\citename}` (package `etoolbox`)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus There is in the answer of the duplicate post.