# biblatex biber no author abbreviation

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using biblatex + biber and some of my citations only have the first author listed, followed by et al. I would like to make all my references include all names no matter what. My current settings are

```
\usepackage[
abbreviate=false,
backend=biber,
backref=true,
refsection=chapter,
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
sortlocale=en_US,
style=numeric-verb
]{biblatex}
```

But I am still getting references like `Meijaard et al.` in my bibliography. How can I force the names to be presented without abbreviation? `abbreviate=false` apparently does not do it.

The citation entry for this specific example is:

```
@article{Meijaard2007,
author = {Meijaard, Jaap P. and Papadopoulos, Jeremy M. and Ruina, Andy and Schwab, Arend L.},
journal = {Proceedings of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences},
month = aug,
number = {2084},
pages = {1955--1982},
title = {{Linearized dynamics equations for the balance and steer of a bicycle:     a benchmark and review}},
volume = {463},
year = {2007}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the option you are looking for is `maxnames` (or one of its variants)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103933/maxnames-in-biber ?

Comment: You should also read about the `uniquelist` option which is true by default - this automatically sets maxnames on a per-entry basis to automatically disambiguate name lists.

Answer (score 0):

As Corentin mentions, setting maxnames in the biblatex options fixes the issue, so

```
\usepackage[
abbreviate=false,
backend=biber,
backref=true,
refsection=chapter,
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
sortlocale=en_US,
style=numeric-verb,
maxnames=10
]{biblatex}
```

did the trick.