# Change automatically derived citekey in biblatex with alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change the automatically generated citation key of `biblatex` when using the style `alphabetic`. So far I only know the possibility via the field `shorthand`. But I would like to have the citekey automatically derived from the last name of the author and the year. If there are two authors it should be Last Name 1 and Last Name 2 and the year. If there are more than two authors it should be Last Name 1 et al. and the year. Is there e.g. the possibility to address the year and last name within a bibitem (e.g. `bibauthorlastname`) and do something like

```
@article{articleA,
title={This is a long title of article A},
author={Albert Einstein},
journal={Some scienece journal},
volume={1},
number={4},
pages={42--125},
year=1950,
publisher={Hellsevier}, 
shorthand = {\bibauthorlastname \bibyear}
}
```

Or do I have to approach the matter in a completely different way?

Here is a MWE, where the citekey entry is formatted as it should be (but not automatically).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[                        
    backend=biber,                  
    bibencoding=utf8,               
    style=alphabetic        
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleA,
title={This is a long title of article A},
author={Albert Einstein},
journal={Some scienece journal},
volume={1},
number={4},
pages={42--125},
year=1950,
publisher={Hellsevier}, 
shorthand = {Einstein 1950}
}

@article{articleB,
title={This is a long title of article B},
author={Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger},
journal={Another science journal},
volume={42},
number={1},
pages={43--49},
year=1970,
publisher={Hellsevier},
shorthand = {Boltzmann and Schrödinger 1970}
}

@article{articleC,
title={This is a long title of article C},
author={Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger and Werner Heisenberg},
journal={Another science journal},
volume={4},
number={1},
pages={10--50},
year=1980,
publisher={Hellsevier}, 
shorthand = {Boltzmann et al. 1980}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test for citation \cite{articleA}. And here is another test \cite{articleB} and also \cite{articleC}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maxnames in biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103933/maxnames-in-biber)

Comment: From there: in `biblatex` the `maxnames` option controls when the names will be shown in full and when `et al` is used in the citations.

Comment: @Marijn On the other hand the OP uses `style=alphabetic`, which is not affected by `maxnames`.

Comment: @moewe I see, I overlooked that. However, he could use `authoryear` instead, as you show in your answer.

Comment: @Marijn Quite, but then some additional work is needed to get the desired output, so I would be reluctant to close this question  as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103933/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style you describe is an author-year style, so it seems more straigtforward to base it on `style=authoryear` rather than `style=alphabetic`.

If you want to retain the square brackets around citations and the repetition of the citation label in the bibliography, I suggest you have a look at [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s `ext-authoryear` style. Its citation delimiter feature makes it easy to obtain square brackets instead of the usual round brackets (with `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims`), its `introcite` option makes it easy to repeat the citation label in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxbibnames=999,
  introcite=label,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleA,
  title     = {This is a long title of article A},
  author    = {Albert Einstein},
  journal   = {Some Science Journal},
  volume    = {1},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {42--125},
  year      = 1950,
}
@article{articleB,
  title   = {This is a long title of article B},
  author  = {Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger},
  journal = {Another Science Journal},
  volume  = {42},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {43--49},
  year    = 1970,
}
@article{articleC,
  title   = {This is a long title of article C},
  author  = {Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger and Werner Heisenberg},
  journal = {Another Science Journal},
  volume  = {4},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {10--50},
  year    = 1980,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test for citation \autocite{articleA}.
And here is another test \autocite{articleB}
and also \autocite{articleC}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a test for citation [Einstein 1950]. And here is another test [Boltzmann und Schrödinger 1970] and also [Boltzmann et al. 1980].]

Comment: Is there a way to implement the whole thing without using biblatex-ext? The problem is that the ShareLaTeX instance I am working on probably uses an older Tex distribution that does not include the package. I tried to copy the relevant content from the package into the code above to make it available, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @Nico Are you using ShareLaTeX on a server of your university/institution? The online version of ShareLaTeX merged with Overleaf a while ago and Overleaf just got TeX live 2019 (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2019-upgrade-january-2020) (`biblatex-ext` is included in TeX live 2019 and in updated versions of TeX live 2018), so if you start a new project there, you should be able to use `biblatex-ext`. Unfortunately, the code for the two main features used here is quite elaborate and porting it to an (to me unknown and untestable) version of LaTeX is a pain.

Comment: Yes, we operate our own ShareLaTeX server at our institute. Unfortunately, I have no access rights to the administration of the server, so I can't make updates or install packages manually. My own packages are simply uploaded as .sty files to my projects, so I thought that this might be possible with biblatex-ext as well.

Comment: Just adding \usepackage{hyperref} to your MWE links only the "date-part" of the shorthand. Is it possible to have the whole shorthand linked?

Comment: @Nico Theoretically yes, but it can be tricky, so my advice is to accept the status quo. If you absolutely want to have links that extend to the author name, my go-to link is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864. If that does not work I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The code in that answer works perfectly.